# SQL Error: 1038: An object or column name is missing or empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Currently I'm working with windows credentials, when i trying to create a user with SQL Authentication encountered the attached error. I have seen it is due to empty login name. How to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: what version of SSMS are you using ?

Comment: @KIN I'm using SSMS 2014

Comment: Can you post the t-sql or the ssms window? Are you trying to create a sql login without specifying a name?

Comment: What happens when you do this with proper commands (e.g. `CREATE LOGIN`) instead of pointing and clicking through the GUI? Can you at least better describe what you populated in the GUI before clicking OK, which led to this error? Can you press the script button instead of OK, and show us that? Is it possible this error is actually coming from a DDL trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create empty login?

```
CREATE LOGIN [] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
```

If we run above in the SSMS query window, we get below error message:

> Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Line 1 An object or column name is
>   missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a
>   name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases
>   defined as “” or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Now the error makes sense;

> Because login is created as [] and error clearly says that “…[] are
>   not allowed…”

Solution:

> **The issue was caused because of the empty login name. If we provide name, then the issue will be resolved.**

For more info check  [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)